# :before not showing when overflow is auto

Tags: css, overflow, tumblr

So I'm making this tumblr theme that uses the :before for icons, like this:

```
    /* Icons */
    ol#posts li:before{
        content:"";
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:-46px;
        width:32px;
        height:24px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        // tried: overflow:visible;
    }
    li.text:before{
        background:url('http://i.imgur.com/z5YtE.png');
    }
    [...]
```

But when I set the overflow of li.post to auto, the icons won't show.

```
    li.post{
        position:relative;
        max-height:400px;
        overflow-x:auto;
    }
```

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have giving yourself the answer, "when I set the overflow of li.post to auto, the icons won't show."

remove overflow-x

What you are doing is, if there is more content then an undefined width, then show a scrollbar.

You have not set a with, so scrollbar will never show up and all icons that are not in the container li.post normal view are not visible (*because absolute positioning*).

Comment: For future reference, I just used and inner div with the max height and overflow auto, and that worked.